# jQuery form serialization submitted with an extra id

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form like this:

```
 <form id="cform">
    <label>folder name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Folder[name]" />
    <input id="cfolder" type="submit" value="create" />
 </form>
```

I want to submit the form in jQuery ajax, so I have code like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/folder/create",
    data: $('#cform').serialize(),
    success: function(msg){
        //sucess
    }
  });
```

this is all easy so far, but now I want to submit an extra dynamic id($id value is available) along with the whole form. how Can I do that? I tried this:

```
 data: $('#cform').serialize()+"&Folder[id]="+$id,
```

but it didn't work, the server side did not get the id. the tricky part here for me is Folder[name], Folder[id],
because the server side recevie the data in php like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Folder'])){
    //assign data here
}
```

hope this is clear and thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Are you just missing a `+` maybe? `+"&Folder[id]=" + $id`? What is `$id`?

Comment: sorry, I am only missing that here,it is updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative suggestion:

You can use [`.serializeArray` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) and [`$.param` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). Then jQuery will take care of all the encoding:

```
var data = $('#cform').serializeArray();
data.push({name: "Folder[id]", value: $id});

// later

data: $.param(data);
```

---

I don't understand if you have a problem with `$_POST['Folder']` or not, but if you use names with brackets at the end, PHP will parse the data into an array.

Thus you can access the data with `$_POST['Folder']['name']` and `$_POST['Folder']['id']`.

For more information have a look at [*Variables From External Sources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

Comment: @bingjie2680: What does `var_dump($_POST)` give you? Are you sure the data is *not* send? Or maybe you access it the wrong way? Does `$id` contain a value?

Comment: hi, Flelix kling, I tried var_damp($_post), and it seems I get the id..let me try again.I ll come back

Comment: @bingjie2680: I thought so ;) You just have to access it the right way: `$_POST['Folder']['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

How about sending data this way -

```
data: $('#cform').serialize()+"&FolderId=" + $id
```

then try checking for `$_POST['FolderId']` on the back-end?

An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rQyqk/) on jsfiddle.

Comment: it does not work, I guess we can use &FolderId instead of &Folder[id]

Comment: @bingjie2680: What do you mean by that? What problems do you have with it?

Comment: @bingjie2680: I don't understand. A name like `Folder[name]` will PHP make the data parse into an array. The name is then available via `$_POST['Folder']['name']` and the id via `$_POST['Folder']['id']`. That is normally the intention behind using names with brackets.

Answer (score 0):

you does not use this

```
`data: $('#cform').serialize()+"&Folder[id]="+$id,`
```

to concatenate , use this one

```
data: $('#cform').serialize()+"&Folderid="+$id,
```

and in php file get it by

```
if(isset($_POST['Folderid'])){
    //assign data here
}
```