# Parse text with multiple strings in brackets into arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

I have a problem with parsing something like this:

```
{form_settings['settings']['title']: "Titulek", form_settings['settings']['description']: "Popisek formuláře...", form_settings['settings']['gdpr']: "ip", form_settings['settings']['acquisition']: "n", form_settings['settings']['style_form']: "without_border", …}
```

I want something like in the PHP, where you can call this

```
$form_settings['settings']['title']
```

But you can't do it in javascript and i want to use similiar array like in the php I want to do something like that

```
form_settings['settings']['title']
```

Because it doesn't work, do you know how to parse it? Thanks for the answers!

//EDIT

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-form-label">
  <input type="text" id="title-for-receiver" class="form-control" name="form_settings['email']['{$input_form['EMAIL']['title_for_receiver']->name}']" value={$input_form['EMAIL']['title_for_receiver']->value} />
</div>
```

And I got these values through javascript

```
function getFormData(form){
var unindexed_array = form.serializeArray();
var indexed_array = {};

$.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
    indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
});

return indexed_array;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about parsing strings or targeting nested arrays? That doesn't look like valid JavaScript syntax, so I'm not sure what you're after.

Comment: I mean, that's not valid JSON.  Why not make it valid JSON?

Comment: Yeah I want to parse it and save those strings in brackets to the arrays, which are named like the first string in bracket. So if you do something like tihs:
form_settings['settings']['title'] you will get a Titulek string.

Comment: I've got them from html, because I have a name="form_settings['settings']['title']" and I got it by javascript I have more of these names on the same page, but there are different second bracket names. And I want to do it like in PHP.

Comment: If you do `form_settings['settings']['title']` in JavaScript you'll get only the title string. (I had to look up "titulek".)

Comment: Are you familiar with object notation in javascript?  `x['a']['b']['c']` would follow the pattern of `var x = {a:{b:{c:'my value'}}}`

Comment: something like `thing:"form_settings[settings][title]"`

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6580961/125981

Comment: If I do the form_settings['settings']['title']. There comes an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Comment: In that example, `settings` would be a key in an object, not an array element. Is that what you have?

Comment: Yeah and the settings element is an array and there is another one element like title and this is the element, which have some string in it ("Titulek") for example.

Comment: I'm sorry, none of this or the comments are shedding a whole lot of light. Is what you are trying to parse a *string*? You want to turn it into a JavaScript *object* ? _fyi_ It can't be an *array* because arrays are `indexed`, not `key->value` pairs. Lastly, unlike PHP, in JavaScript you have to declare your variables. `form_settings` has to be  declared before you try to assign anything at all to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can parse.  That "parse" indicates a string or something that can be. THIS: cannot be "parsed":

1. It has both single `'` and double `"` quotes so NEITHER will work to make it a string which is a parse-able object.
2. It has internal elements with no quotes also

> {form_settings['settings']['title']: "Titulek",
>   form_settings['settings']['description']: "Popisek formuláře...",
>   form_settings['settings']['gdpr']: "ip",
>   form_settings['settings']['acquisition']: "n",
>   form_settings['settings']['style_form']: "without_border", …}

EDIT: I added `mythingString` and the parse of that to be more patently obvious.

Perhaps pass a better object:

```js
var mything = {
  "form_settings['settings']['title']": "Titulek",
  "form_settings['settings']['description']": "Popisek formuláře...",
  "form_settings['settings']['gdpr']": "ip",
  "form_settings['settings']['acquisition']": "n",
  "form_settings['settings']['style_form']": "without_border"
};

console.log(mything["form_settings['settings']['title']"]);

var mything2 = {
  form_settings: {
    settings: {
      'title': "Titulek",
      'description': "Popisek formuláře...",
      'gdpr': "ip",
      'acquisition': "n",
      'style_form': "without_border"
    }
  }
};
console.log(mything2.form_settings['settings']['title']);
console.log(mything2.form_settings.settings.title);

var mythingString = '{"form_settings[settings][title]": "Titulek",  "form_settings[settings][description]": "Popisek formuláře...", "form_settings[settings][gdpr]": "ip",  "form_settings[settings][acquisition]": "n", "form_settings[settings][style_form]": "without_border"}';

var parsedThing = JSON.parse(mythingString);
console.log(parsedThing["form_settings[settings][title]"]);
```

Comment: Yes that is the thing I want to do from the first "mything" to "mything2", I want to get it from HTML "name" and inside the elements mything2.form_settings['settings']['title'] would be value with title. How can I do that?

Comment: @Miškyns  So, first get `mything` you do not have that.  That is the point.